# How to use 'and' with 'on' condition of joins in knex

Tags: mysql, knex.js

I am trying to generate a query like:

```
select ifnull(t1.name, ‘default’) as name
from tab1 as t1
left join tab2 as t2 
 on t1.id=t2.id and t2.code=“someValue”
```

I wrote this in knex:

```
var query = knex().from(’tab1’).join(’tab2', function() {

    this.on('tab1.id', '=', 'tab2.id').andOn('tab2.code', '=', 'someValue')
}, 

‘left')
.column([

knex.raw(‘IFNULL(tab1.name, "no name") as name')

]);
```

This does not execute as it treats 'someValue' as a column.
How can I apply 'and' condition in this case?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
var query = knex().from('tab1').join('tab2', function() {
   this.on('tab1.id', '=', 'tab2.id')
   .on('tab2.code', '=', knex.raw('?', ['someValue']))
}, 'left')
.column([knex.raw('IFNULL(tab1.name, "no name") as name')]);
```

Using knex.raw for quoting someValue as string did the trick.
Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Maaan, saved my evening ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Not well documented but you can now use `onVal`, and any of its and / or variants.

So, instead of

```
.on('tab2.code', '=', knex.raw('?', ['someValue']))
```

You can simply write:

```
const query = knex()
  .from('tab1')
  .join('tab2', function() {
     this.on('tab1.id', '=', 'tab2.id')
     this.andOnVal('tab2.code', '=', 'someValue')
}, 'left')
.column([knex.raw('IFNULL(tab1.name, "no name") as name')]);
```

Comment: I couldn't find it on the document. Thank you! How do you know about this?  You read their source code, don't you?

Comment: objection is mostly a wrapper for knex and these helper methods come directly from the knex. Added in 0.16.1: `Added onVal and the associated not / and / or methods `
My recommendation is to also check the knex documentation for additional methods. They are most likely also available to objection.

Answer (score 2):

I had to use `knex.raw('?', ['someValue'])` instead of `knex.raw('someValue')`.

For me (using Knex 0.13.0) the accepted solution 
`.on('tab2.code', '=', knex.raw('someValue')` 
produced the query: 
`tab2.code = someValue` (**without quotes**) 
which then caused an `Unknown column someValue` error.

Using `.on('tab2.code', '=', knex.raw('?', ['someValue']))` produced the intended `tab2.code = 'someValue'` (**with quotes**) comparing `tab2.code` to a string literal rather than a column.

Answer (score 2):

*All of the answers above are good, but if you want to go with a single line without a callback, this syntax is for you.* **And custom value you need to represent without quotes**

```
knex('tab1').join('tab2',{'tab1.id':'tab2.id','tab2.code':someValue})
```